# Is holding static reference to multiple objects in abstract class OK?

Tags: java, performance, inheritance

Is there anything significantly bad in terms of performance, memory consumption, design etc about below pattern ?

```
public abstract class A {
    public static final D d = new D();
    public static final C c = new C();
    ......... and many more member of class B, C, and D; like hundreds
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class C extends B {
}

public class D extends C {
}
```

Comment: I'd be most worried about the design.

Comment: No, but there is probably a big design problem. I can't imagine a good reason to have hundreds of individual static final objects, especially if they're not inside some collection.

Comment: You probably want to use an interface if the whole purpose of the class is to hold static objects

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Forgetting performance, it's a very dubious practice -- Your abstract class should not have such explicit awareness of its subtypes.

Comment: @Arkadiy It is existing code not written by me. I just needed to add few more members into class A. But as other pointed out, I see big design flow but the seniors who wrote it think otherwise.

Comment: Its irrelevant to performance. Sorry but you're kinda asking the wrong question here. Don't worry so much about performance, worry more about design. This is not proper OOP. After you get an implementation then you can test bottlenecks and worry about performance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything significantly bad in terms of performance, memory consumption, design etc about below pattern ?

1. **performance** - not really.
2. **memory** - no, if you (1) have predictable bound on how many internal objects will be created (and you are ok with memory they will occupy), (2) have a good idea of lifespan of these objects, (3) you are confident that your abstract class wont be leaked. Otherwise, the answer is *maybe*.
3. **design** - yes. What you are trying to do smells badly from design point of view. It is really hard to tell what you are actually trying to achieve, but the chance that you can design your architecture better is rather high.

Answer (score -3):

There is nothing wrong with it.

I would recommend using an interface though:

```
public interface A {
    D d = new D();
    C c = new C();
    ......... and many more member of class B, C, and D; like hundreds
}
```

Because by default interface members which are fields are treated as `public static final` members, which is precisely what you were doing with the abstract class.

I only recommend this if the abstract class (as implied by your question) only holds those static fields. Otherwise, the way you currently have it is fine.

#### Edit: OP added question about design

In terms of design, it is a bad design because the abstract class is aware of it's subtypes rather than simply relying on specifying it's behaviour and leaving the rest to some other class which can aggregate both the parent and the children's behaviour to achieve some other result.

What I would do in this case is to make the child classes independent of each other, by having them only implement their behaviour which does not rely on `A`

So you will have a class:

```
public class B {

}

public class C {

}

public class D {

}
```

Now you create another class:

```
public class UseBCD {
    public static final B b;
    public static final C c;
    public static final D d;
    // define all the behaviour of class A, plus use the classes as you like
}
```

Now you have the dependency as unidirectional rather being tightly coupled.

If you find that you cannot have `B`, `C`, and `D`, seperate, then it is most likely the case that you actually only need one class that does everything `A, B, C, and D` does.

Comment: That's an anti-pattern. An interface is designed to be implemented. And that's not the case here. Just use a regular final class, with a private constructor. And use static imports if you want to use the constant without prefixing it with the class name.

Comment: To that point, if you're going to recommend something, explain the reasoning behind that recommendation.

Comment: @JBNizet
How is that not the case? Did you not see the other classes in the OP's question that extend the abstract class? How is using a final class going to help that?

Comment: The _case_ refers to you using an interface with state, instead of behavior, which is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @smac89 For a little more insight, this is called the [constant interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface)